# identity server 4, Asp.net identity and

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, postman, identityserver4

I am trying to integrate identity server 4 with asp.net identity, the documentation is very good https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html

But I would like to be able to make the connection without going through the login page, but to make a direct access via a simple GET while passing the parameters.

I found this article: https://damienbod.com/2017/04/14/asp-net-core-identityserver4-resource-owner-password-flow-with-custom-userrepository/

with this method

```
var response = await _httpClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
{
    Address = _disco.TokenEndpoint,

    ClientId = "resourceownerclient",
    ClientSecret = "dataEventRecordsSecret",
    Scope = "email openid dataEventRecords offline_access",

    UserName = user,
    Password = password
});
```

But can't make it work with Postman
[image: Postman]

I have an "invalid_request" error

Here is the client's statement:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "resourceownerclient",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
    IdentityTokenLifetime = 3600,
    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
    SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 30,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
    Enabled = true,
    ClientSecrets=  new List<Secret> { new Secret("dataEventRecordsSecret".Sha256()) },
    AllowedScopes = {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId, 
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
        "dataEventRecords"
    },
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser=true
}
```

What is the recommended way to be able to use Asp.net Identity in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `grant_type` in your postman request:

```
POST /connect/token

    client_id=resourceownerclient&
    client_secret=dataEventRecordsSecret&
    grant_type=password&
    username=damienbod&
    password=damienbod&
    scope=email%20openid%20dataEventRecords%20offline_access
```

Not sure if this is the only issue you have but it definitely one of them.  The identityserver logs will contain more details of what is wrong with the request if this is not the only problem.